# Webpack importing module from different chunk instead of up-to-date version available in the same chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

Long-story short: I need to be able to do something like this:

```
output: {
    moduleId: '[name].[contenthash].js',    
},
```

[Here's a repo for reproducing this error](https://github.com/Jeandcc/webpack-demo)

---

Now the long version:

In short: I have 1 JS file that is available on all pages, and 1 JS file specific for each page of my application. So far, pretty normal. (Ex: one global.js, and one login.js)

The not-so-normal aspect of my application is that **those two files might not have been built/compiled at the same time**. (There's a reason for this but not worth getting into on this post)

Here's the problem: Let's suppose both files use a Localization class I created. The global.js file imports it into its chunk, and the login.js file imports the same class/module. Now let's suppose that that specific global.js file was created 1 month before login.js, and therefore is missing a couple of methods I added to the localization class while working on login.js.

For some reason, **the login.js chunk is not using the class that is available inside its own file**, as it seems like some caching mechanism is **causing it to use the outdated class that is available in the global.js chunk instead**. That causes the code in login.js to call undefined methods of the class, given that they didn`t exist by the time that global.js was created.

When exploring the entries/chunks, I see that the **localization file that holds the class I mentioned gets the same key (786) in the global chunk and in the login chunk**. This seems to be the reason why Webpack's caching mechanism assumes they are both the same file and only loads the one it finds first.

(If I manually change the key in the outputted login.js file, from 786 to a random number, it starts working as expected)

Is there anything I can do to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The trick was to create a plugin that let's me decide what ID to give to modules. The changes required are shown in the commit below.

https://github.com/Jeandcc/webpack-demo/commit/89d8ad1c7b8a0dd1156f3847aa95765b1a1de8a3

This plugin simply assigns the module an ID that is a combination of its name with the buildHash, which should help differentiating modules that were built on different times.